# Kubernetes Ingress does not match host

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I'm trying to create an ingress rule for a backend service. The ingress controller is the Microk8s Nginx ingress. If I set the host, the ingress stops matching the backend, resulting in a 404 when I visit https://my-host.com

Here is my code:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "my-host.com"
      secretName: nginx-ingress
  rules:
    - host: "my-host.com"
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: some-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created 2 rules, one with only `host` and a second with `http: ...`.
It should be

```
rules:
    - host: "my-host.com"
      http:
        paths:
```

Yes, YAML is evil.

Comment: Holy bananas, don't I feel silly now :D. Thanks a bunch